# Как в Eclipse копировать файлы после завершения сборки?

Tags: eclipse

Есть проект на C++, который собирается в Eclipse. Условно структура папок такая:

```
project
- bin
- src
  - exe
  - res
```

После каждого билда надо копировать содержимое папки res в папку bin. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо добавить отдельный сборщик - ant-файл. Добавляете в проект файл с расширением xml, например, build.xml. Там прописываете что-то типа такого:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="HelloWorld" default="HelloWorld" basedir=".">
    <target name="copy">
        <copy todir="from">
            <fileset dir="to" />
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

Идете в Project - Properties - Builders - New. Там добавляете новый сборщик, указав путь к build.xml и рабочую папку. В принципе и все.