# Как в Eclipse для ant-файла определить путь к проекту?

Tags: ant, eclipse

Создаю в Eclipse свой билдер согласно [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/92450#92457).

```
<target name="copy">
    <copy todir="${project_path}\from">
        <fileset dir="${project_path}\from" />
    </copy>
</target>
```

Прописываю полный путь как `${project_path}\...`, получаю ошибку вида

> `BUILD FAILED ...\${project_path}\from does not exist.`

Как ее исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно взять из переменной:

```
${basedir}
```

которая задается так (взято из вашего примера):

```
<project name="HelloWorld" default="HelloWorld" basedir=".">
```

с другой стороны если вы работаете с файлами которые лежат в папке с проэктом то можно обойтись без абсолютных путей и работать с относительными. опять же смотрите свой пример